# Working with scripts in MVC

Tags: javascript, html, ruby

For performance efficiency, is there a way to not include scripts for certain pages?  I am currently using Ruby, specifically Shopify's application and on some pages, it isn't necessary to have scripts of jQuery as there are no functionalities that require them.  From my understanding, the template page is given to every page which includes the scripts.  Is there a way to disable them for certain pages?

Answer (score 0):

U can use form sections in template and such sections can be filled from views that use those templates. Populating from each view can be a workaround. If not use a different layout all together.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an amd loader like require.js or browserify to load in the scripts on the pages you need them. However, it's generally better practice to load all the scripts you need for your entire site in one hit, to reduce lots of http requests. That is better for performance because once the script has downloaded for page X, page Y will just load it from the client browsers cache anyway. It depends on how big your site is, but generally you create the site on the premise and hope that people will visit most of your pages.